# Web Service Security java

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jax-ws

My web service was created some time back using IBM JAX-RPC. As a part of enhancement, I need to provide some security to the existing service.

One way is to provide a handler, all the request and response will pass through that handler only. In the request I can implement some authentication rules for each and every application/user accessing it.

Other than this, What are the possible ways for securing it?

I have heard someting called wsse security for web service. Is it possible to implement it for the JAX-RPC? Or it can be implemented only for JAX-WS? Need some helpful inputs on the wsse security so that i can jump learning it.

Other than handler and wsse security, any other possible way to make a service secure?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

JAX-RPC and Document-Literal are two different ways of creating SOAP webservices. For adding the security, check out [OASIS](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=security). You have to add the the policy tag and additional layer of encryption to the SOAP message